# Is there a way to have a GridView with dynamic cell size?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, gridview

In android, the gridview provides an excellent way to arrange items neatly. However, the cell size for a grid is fixed. That is, in a 3 column by 4 rows grid, if the very first item is 10 dp in height and the second and third items are 20 dp in height, then all the cells in first row will be of 20 dp height.

I want to find a way where in, the view will automatically adjust the cell size for the first cell, so that items below the first item of 10dp height are displayed immediately below it, instead of leaving that  extra 10dp gap.

This is the sort of behaviour we can see in Windows live tiles. The items below small tiles move up to fill the gap. I want to implement a similar functionality.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: did not quite get the arrangement you are  talking about .. Have a look a [Flexboxlayoutmanager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) maybe it can help ..

Comment: @ADM that isn't quite what I was looking for. It resizes item widths but row size is still fixed. I need a dynamic cell size

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, there was already a way to do this. I just didn't know the right term for it.

Android provides a StaggeredGridLayout Layout Manager that does just what I need. 
[You can take a look at this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGHs9.png)
Also, visit  [this page](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html) to see it in action.